# Is this sentence grammatically correct? [emphasizing a clause]

Tags: grammaticality

In today's grammar course, we saw an example sentence about emphasizing a whole clause:

It was ***because they were playing in London*** that England had an advantage.

Our teacher has asked us to give a similar example, and one student has given the answer:

It was because ***he was taller than her*** that gave him an advantage.

Although it didn't follow the exact same pattern, the teacher said it was grammatically correct. I can't verbally explain it but the sentence somehow feels strange to me, is this sentence grammatically correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds clumsy. Maybe: It was because he was taller that gave him an advantage _over her_.

Comment: "It was because he was taller than her that gave him an advantage over her".

Comment: The reason it sounds strange is because we would normally expect the sentence to read: It was because he was taller than her that *he gained/had* an advantage. But instead of using the pronoun *he* as the subject, the sentence uses *him* as the indirect object.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I'd opt for: _He had an advantage because he was taller than her_ – but that's a different grammar lesson, I suppose.

Comment: Note that *because he was taller than her* is not a noun phrase, so it can't be used as the subject of the verb ***gave***. To create a credible noun phrase there you'd need something like *It was **the fact that** he was taller than her that gave him an advantage.*

Comment: 'It was because they were playing in London that England had an advantage.' is an it-clefted rewrite of 'England had an advantage because they were playing in London.'  // 'It was because he was taller than her that gave him an advantage.' is a rewrite of 'He was given an advantage because he was taller than her.' I'd say this is unacceptable.